# How to decode html special character with string limit?

Tags: php, laravel

How can I decode HTML special character along with string limit?

This line does not work:

```
<p>{!!\Str::limit($event->description,180,"..")!!}<a href="#">View Detail</a></p>
```

but if I used  it normaly for string limit it would:

```
<p>{{\Str::limit($event->description,180,"..")}}<a href="#">View Detail</a></p>
```

The above line works with string limit but not decode.

Comment: What are you trying to display to the screen exactly? Does $event->description contain HTML tags? Do you want those HTML tags to display with HTML formatting to the screen?

Comment: If you want to decode HTML special chars you can use the PHP function: htmlspecialchars_decode inside your Str::limit() function.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't entirely clear what `$event->description` contains.  Also, isn't entirely clear what `\Str` represents, or even what version of Laravel you are using.  The below examples assume you are meaning `Illuminate\Support\Str` and on version 5.8.XX, and I am including two different description variables.

```
$description = "<p><strong>Lorem ipsum</strong> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. &quot;Ut augue orci, pellentesque at metus sed, tempor ultrices diam.&quot; Quisque tempor ullamcorper nunc, vitae efficitur justo tristique sed. Sed ac orci condimentum, viverra mi quis, pharetra sapien. Suspendisse nec nisi sem. </p>\n";

$descEncoded = "&lt;p&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Lorem ipsum&lt;/strong&gt; dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. &amp;quot;Ut augue orci, pellentesque at metus sed, tempor ultrices diam.&amp;quot; Quisque tempor ullamcorper nunc, vitae efficitur justo tristique sed. Sed ac orci condimentum, viverra mi quis, pharetra sapien. Suspendisse nec nisi sem. Sed porta finibus posuere. Nunc a libero vitae mi ornare interdum.&lt;/p&gt;";
```

**html_entity_decode:**

```
{!!\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(html_entity_decode($description),180,"...")!!}
{!!\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(html_entity_decode($descEncoded),180,"...")!!}
```

[image: html_entity_decode output]

**htmlspecialchars_decode:**

```
{!!\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(htmlspecialchars_decode($description),180,"...")!!}
{!!\Illuminate\Support\Str::limit(htmlspecialchars_decode($descEncoded),180,"...")!!}
```

[image: htmlspecialchars_decode output]

Hopefully this helps your cause.  If you update the question with more specifics, I can adjust the answer as needed.